# Which Magento Cron Jobs are required for good practice?

Tags: cron, ce-1.9.1.0

Are there any cron jobs that are recommended to run for a Magento store?  I read somewhere about running one that clears the cache (or something, I'm not sure now).

I just wondered whether people had a recommended set of cron jobs set up for their own stores?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure regarding the recommended cron jobs for Magento. But as per my view it will be good if you have set below cron jobs:

1) As Magento 1.9.1 sends emails in queue, it is must to set the cron for sending emails.

2) Index Management is pretty important part too. I would recommend to set a cron for reindexing atleast once a day.

3) If you are using multi-currency website, you should import the currency rates twice a day using cron.

4) To reduce the load on database, log cleaning should be done regularly. You should remove logs older than month or two based on your requirements.

I am not sure about removing the caches regularly but surely caches should be updated regularly.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably thinking about log cleaning under system -> configuration -> system -> log cleaning. The database log tables can really get bloated so certainly a good idea to turn this on.

Other jobs that are useful like re-indexing will run without you having to do anything (assuming you have your server cron configured to run Magento cron), but you might want to also turn on currency rate updating if you are using multiple currencies for your store under system -> configuration -> currency setup -> scheduled import settings.

Answer (score 1):

A few features in Magento require a script to be run periodically. These features include, but are not limited to:

```
Catalog Price rules
Sending Newsletters
Generating Google Sitemaps
Customer Alerts/Notifications (product price change, product back to stock)
Automatic updating of currency rates
Scheduled DB logs cleanup
```

You can check on Magento officical site - http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job